# What is the fundamental difference between post WW2 German and post Cold War Chinese model of industrialization?

Tags: china

What is the fundamental difference between post-WW2 German and post Cold War Chinese model of rapid industrialization?

Is there any similarity?

Comment: Hmm... Basically the cold war was 1947 to 1991. China didn't really get going on industrialization until about 1980 and has been expanding like mad ever since.  From an industrialization point of view, China didn't really much care about the cold war.

Answer (score 2):

Germany was an industrialized nation pre-WW2, so it wasn't so much an industrialization but a rebuilding of the damaged/destroyed infrastructure.

China's industrialization happened during the cold war, I'd say, not post - they just increased their speed since the end of the cold war.